# Programmatically determine how many parameters in a stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there anything in the catalog views in SQL Server that will give you a list of the stored procedures like `select name from sys.procedures` that will also tell you how many parameters each procedure takes?  Intellisense will take you the names of the parameters and Visual Studio knows as well.  Is there a better way to get a result of of stored procedures and the number (and/or name) of the parameters each procedure takes?

I suppose one could do this is they parsed sp_helptext 'sprocName' but I would think there is a better way to do it.

Dig a little more digging and came up with

```
;with x
as
(
SELECT 
    p.name AS Parameter,        
    t.name AS [Type],
    sp.name
FROM sys.procedures sp
JOIN sys.parameters p 
    ON sp.object_id = p.object_id
JOIN sys.types t
    ON p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
)
select name,Parameter,COUNT(*)
from x
group by name,Parameter
```

which'll do the job.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a .NET language (you mentioned Visual Studio) or directly inside of TSQL?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter how about inside Visual Studio since I found a TSQL soltuion (and you can't just make a stored procedure of the above TSQL :))

Comment: There's a better way, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at the parameter info like so:

```
declare @ProcedureName sysname;
set @ProcedureName = '[dbo].[YourProcedureName]';

select  sp.name, 
        spa.name, 
        spa.is_output 
from    sys.procedures sp
join    sys.parameters spa on
        sp.object_id = spa.object_id
where   sp.object_id = object_id(@ProcedureName);
```

Comment: just curious, why did you create the variable instead of just making the Where clause where `sp.name='x'`

Comment: Just habit I guess, in case you would be taking it in from DAL call, etc.  Using `object_id` allows you to pass a DatabaseId as well as schema for the name resolution.

Comment: Ah, neat.  I'll have to file this away in my tool box.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one out :

```
select * from information_schema.parameters
where specific_name='your_procedure_name'
```

Answer (score 2):

If, as you mentioned, you're using a .NET language for this, you can use [DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) method of SqlCommandBuilder. This way you don't have to write anything in the backend and do this purely in .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting procedures, provided by Microsoft. You can choose right piece of data from it. See also [System Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961.aspx)

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

create procedure sys.sp_sproc_columns_90 
(
    @procedure_name         nvarchar(390) = '%',
    @procedure_owner        nvarchar(384) = null,
    @procedure_qualifier    sysname = null,
    @column_name            nvarchar(384) = null,
    @ODBCVer                int = 2,
    @fUsePattern            bit = 1 -- To allow users to explicitly disable all pattern matching.
)
as
    declare @group_num_lower smallint
    declare @group_num_upper smallint
    declare @semi_position int
    declare @full_procedure_name nvarchar(775) -- 390 + 1 + 384
    declare @procedure_id int

    if @procedure_qualifier is not null
    begin
        if db_name() <> @procedure_qualifier
        begin
            if @procedure_qualifier = ''
            begin
                -- in this case, we need to return an empty result set
                -- because the user has requested a database with an empty name
                select @procedure_name = ''
                select @procedure_owner = ''
            end
            else
            begin   -- If qualifier doesn't match current database
                raiserror (15250, -1,-1)
                return
            end
        end
    end

    if @procedure_name is null
    begin   -- If procedure name not supplied, match all
        select @procedure_name = '%'
    end

    -- first we need to extract the procedure group number, if one exists
    select @semi_position = charindex(';',@procedure_name)
    if (@semi_position > 0)
    begin   -- If group number separator (;) found
        select @group_num_lower = convert(int,substring(@procedure_name, @semi_position + 1, 2))
        select @group_num_upper = @group_num_lower
        select @procedure_name = substring(@procedure_name, 1, @semi_position -1)
    end
    else
    begin   -- No group separator, so default to all groups
        select @group_num_lower = 0
        select @group_num_upper = 32767         
    end

    if @procedure_owner is null
    begin   -- If unqualified procedure name
        select @full_procedure_name = quotename(@procedure_name)
    end
    else
    begin   -- Qualified procedure name
        if @procedure_owner = ''
        begin   -- If empty owner name
            select @full_procedure_name = quotename(@procedure_owner)
        end
        else
        begin
            select @full_procedure_name = quotename(@procedure_owner) + '.' + quotename(@procedure_name)
        end
    end

    select @procedure_id = object_id(@full_procedure_name)


    if (@fUsePattern = 1) -- Does the user want it?
    begin
        if ((isnull(charindex('%', @full_procedure_name),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('[', @procedure_name),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('[', @procedure_owner),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('_', @full_procedure_name),0) = 0) and
            (@procedure_id is not null))
        begin
            select @fUsePattern = 0 -- not a single wild char, so go the fast way.
        end
    end

    if @fUsePattern = 0
    begin
        /* -- Debug output, do not remove it.
        print '*************'
        print 'No pattern matching.'
        print isnull(convert(sysname, @procedure_id),   '@procedure_id = null')
        print isnull(@full_procedure_name,              '@full_procedure_name = null')
        print isnull(@procedure_name,                   '@procedure_name = null')
        print isnull(@procedure_owner,                  '@procedure_owner = null')
        print isnull(@procedure_qualifier,              '@procedure_qualifier = null')
        print isnull(@column_name,                      '@column_name = null')
        print isnull(@ODBCVer,                          '@ODBCVer = null')
        print '*************'
        */

        --
        -- FAST!
        --
        select
            PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER         = s_scov.PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER,
            PROCEDURE_OWNER             = s_scov.PROCEDURE_OWNER,
            PROCEDURE_NAME              = convert(nvarchar(134),
                                            s_scov.PROCEDURE_NAME +';'+ ltrim(str(s_scov.procedure_number,5))),
            COLUMN_NAME                 = s_scov.COLUMN_NAME,
            COLUMN_TYPE                 = s_scov.COLUMN_TYPE,
            DATA_TYPE                   = s_scov.DATA_TYPE,
            TYPE_NAME                   = s_scov.TYPE_NAME,
            "PRECISION"                 = s_scov.PRECISION,
            "LENGTH"                    = s_scov.LENGTH,
            SCALE                       = s_scov.SCALE,
            RADIX                       = s_scov.RADIX,
            NULLABLE                    = s_scov.NULLABLE,
            REMARKS                     = s_scov.REMARKS,
            COLUMN_DEF                  = s_scov.COLUMN_DEF,
            SQL_DATA_TYPE               = s_scov.SQL_DATA_TYPE,
            SQL_DATETIME_SUB            = s_scov.SQL_DATETIME_SUB,
            CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH           = s_scov.CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH,
            ORDINAL_POSITION            = s_scov.ORDINAL_POSITION,
            IS_NULLABLE                 = s_scov.IS_NULLABLE,
            SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME                  = s_scov.SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME                   = s_scov.SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME            = s_scov.SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME = s_scov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME  = s_scov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME         = s_scov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME,
            SS_DATA_TYPE                = s_scov.SS_DATA_TYPE
        from
            sys.spt_sproc_columns_odbc_view s_scov
        where
            s_scov.object_id = @procedure_id and
            s_scov.odbcver = @ODBCVer and
            (@column_name is null or s_scov.COLUMN_NAME = @column_name) and
            (s_scov.procedure_number between @group_num_lower and @group_num_upper)

        UNION ALL

        select         -- procedure return value & table valued functions
            PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER         = s_scrvov.PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER,
            PROCEDURE_OWNER             = s_scrvov.PROCEDURE_OWNER,
            PROCEDURE_NAME              = convert(nvarchar(134),
                                            s_scrvov.PROCEDURE_NAME +';'+ ltrim(str(s_scrvov.procedure_number,5))),
            COLUMN_NAME                 = s_scrvov.COLUMN_NAME,
            COLUMN_TYPE                 = s_scrvov.COLUMN_TYPE,
            DATA_TYPE                   = s_scrvov.DATA_TYPE,
            TYPE_NAME                   = s_scrvov.TYPE_NAME,
            "PRECISION"                 = s_scrvov.PRECISION,
            "LENGTH"                    = s_scrvov.LENGTH,
            SCALE                       = s_scrvov.SCALE,
            RADIX                       = s_scrvov.RADIX,
            NULLABLE                    = s_scrvov.NULLABLE,
            REMARKS                     = s_scrvov.REMARKS,
            COLUMN_DEF                  = s_scrvov.COLUMN_DEF,
            SQL_DATA_TYPE               = s_scrvov.SQL_DATA_TYPE,
            SQL_DATETIME_SUB            = s_scrvov.SQL_DATETIME_SUB,
            CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH           = s_scrvov.CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH,
            ORDINAL_POSITION            = s_scrvov.ORDINAL_POSITION,
            IS_NULLABLE                 = s_scrvov.IS_NULLABLE,
            SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME                  = s_scrvov.SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME                   = s_scrvov.SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME            = s_scrvov.SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME = s_scrvov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME  = s_scrvov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME         = s_scrvov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME,
            SS_DATA_TYPE                = s_scrvov.SS_DATA_TYPE
        from
            sys.spt_sproc_columns_return_values_odbc_view s_scrvov
        where
            s_scrvov.object_id = @procedure_id and
            (
                @column_name is null or 
                @column_name = '@RETURN_VALUE' or
                @column_name = '@TABLE_RETURN_VALUE'
            ) and
            (s_scrvov.procedure_number between @group_num_lower and @group_num_upper)

        order by 1, 2, 3, 18
    end
    else
    begin
        /* -- Debug output, do not remove it.
        print '*************'
        print 'THERE IS pattern matching!'
        print isnull(convert(sysname, @procedure_id),   '@procedure_id = null')
        print isnull(@full_procedure_name,              '@full_procedure_name = null')
        print isnull(@procedure_name,                   '@procedure_name = null')
        print isnull(@procedure_owner,                  '@procedure_owner = null')
        print isnull(@procedure_qualifier,              '@procedure_qualifier = null')
        print isnull(@column_name,                      '@column_name = null')
        print isnull(@ODBCVer,                          '@ODBCVer = null')
        print '*************'
        */

        --
        -- SLOOOOOW!
        --
        if @procedure_owner is null
            select @procedure_owner = '%'

        select
            PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER         = s_scov.PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER,
            PROCEDURE_OWNER             = s_scov.PROCEDURE_OWNER,
            PROCEDURE_NAME              = convert(nvarchar(134),
                                            s_scov.PROCEDURE_NAME +';'+ ltrim(str(s_scov.procedure_number,5))),
            COLUMN_NAME                 = s_scov.COLUMN_NAME,
            COLUMN_TYPE                 = s_scov.COLUMN_TYPE,
            DATA_TYPE                   = s_scov.DATA_TYPE,
            TYPE_NAME                   = s_scov.TYPE_NAME,
            "PRECISION"                 = s_scov.PRECISION,
            "LENGTH"                    = s_scov.LENGTH,
            SCALE                       = s_scov.SCALE,
            RADIX                       = s_scov.RADIX,
            NULLABLE                    = s_scov.NULLABLE,
            REMARKS                     = s_scov.REMARKS,
            COLUMN_DEF                  = s_scov.COLUMN_DEF,
            SQL_DATA_TYPE               = s_scov.SQL_DATA_TYPE,
            SQL_DATETIME_SUB            = s_scov.SQL_DATETIME_SUB,
            CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH           = s_scov.CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH,
            ORDINAL_POSITION            = s_scov.ORDINAL_POSITION,
            IS_NULLABLE                 = s_scov.IS_NULLABLE,
            SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME                  = s_scov.SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME                   = s_scov.SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME            = s_scov.SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME = s_scov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME  = s_scov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME         = s_scov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME,
            SS_DATA_TYPE                = s_scov.SS_DATA_TYPE
        from
            sys.spt_sproc_columns_odbc_view s_scov
        where
            s_scov.PROCEDURE_NAME like @procedure_name and
            (@column_name is null or s_scov.COLUMN_NAME like @column_name) and
            s_scov.odbcver = @ODBCVer and
            (s_scov.procedure_number between @group_num_lower and @group_num_upper) and
            schema_name(s_scov.schema_id) like @procedure_owner

        UNION ALL

        select         -- procedure return value & table valued functions
            PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER         = s_scrvov.PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER,
            PROCEDURE_OWNER             = s_scrvov.PROCEDURE_OWNER,
            PROCEDURE_NAME              = convert(nvarchar(134),
                                            s_scrvov.PROCEDURE_NAME +';'+ ltrim(str(s_scrvov.procedure_number,5))),
            COLUMN_NAME                 = s_scrvov.COLUMN_NAME,
            COLUMN_TYPE                 = s_scrvov.COLUMN_TYPE,
            DATA_TYPE                   = s_scrvov.DATA_TYPE,
            TYPE_NAME                   = s_scrvov.TYPE_NAME,
            "PRECISION"                 = s_scrvov.PRECISION,
            "LENGTH"                    = s_scrvov.LENGTH,
            SCALE                       = s_scrvov.SCALE,
            RADIX                       = s_scrvov.RADIX,
            NULLABLE                    = s_scrvov.NULLABLE,
            REMARKS                     = s_scrvov.REMARKS,
            COLUMN_DEF                  = s_scrvov.COLUMN_DEF,
            SQL_DATA_TYPE               = s_scrvov.SQL_DATA_TYPE,
            SQL_DATETIME_SUB            = s_scrvov.SQL_DATETIME_SUB,
            CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH           = s_scrvov.CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH,
            ORDINAL_POSITION            = s_scrvov.ORDINAL_POSITION,
            IS_NULLABLE                 = s_scrvov.IS_NULLABLE,
            SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME                  = s_scrvov.SS_UDT_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME                   = s_scrvov.SS_UDT_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME            = s_scrvov.SS_UDT_ASSEMBLY_TYPE_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME = s_scrvov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_CATALOG_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME  = s_scrvov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_SCHEMA_NAME,
            SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME         = s_scrvov.SS_XML_SCHEMACOLLECTION_NAME,
            SS_DATA_TYPE                = s_scrvov.SS_DATA_TYPE
        from
            sys.spt_sproc_columns_return_values_odbc_view s_scrvov
        where
            s_scrvov.PROCEDURE_NAME like @procedure_name and 
            schema_name(s_scrvov.schema_id) like @procedure_owner and 
            (
                @column_name is null or 
                @column_name = '@RETURN_VALUE' or
                @column_name = '@TABLE_RETURN_VALUE'
            ) and
            (s_scrvov.procedure_number between @group_num_lower and @group_num_upper)

        order by 1, 2, 3, 18
    end

GO
```